# A PHP regex that just won't work

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have the following snippet:

```
<li>
<div>
<div class="myslider">
<div id="myslider">slide 1 of 6</div>
<div style="clear:both; height: 1px;">
</div>
</div>
```

And want to find and replace `slide 1 of 6` with `""`.

I am using :

```
/slide (\d+) of (\d+)/
```

and nothing, tried a lot of combinations and nothing works. Any help is appreciated - I am using `preg_replace`.

Comment: Can you post the actual PHP code with the regex?

Comment: preg_replace("/slide (\d+) of (\d+)/", "" , $text);

Comment: Also tested it here and doesn't work either - http://www.pagecolumn.com/tool/pregtest.htm

Comment: @Darko your code is working http://codepad.viper-7.com/S9k62x

Comment: With the new lines and everything it's not - as a proof of concept it works fine, that's why i can't figure it out

Comment: I'm so surprised you're having trouble parsing HTML with regular expressions; that's so weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$text = '<li>
<div>
<div class="myslider">
<div id="myslider">slide 1 of 6</div>
<div style="clear:both; height: 1px;">
</div>
</div>';

echo preg_replace("/slide\s*\d+\s*of\s*\d+/", "", $text);
```

output:

```
<li> <div> <div class="myslider"> <div id="myslider"></div> <div style="clear:both; height: 1px;"> </div> </div>
```

[DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/0ip-je8)

Comment: That would work but the htmlspecialchars makes things complicated as I remove the HTML tags later on.

Comment: I just used htmlspecialchars() for test, please remove it when you use it.

Comment: Works great! I wasn't echoing it or assigning it to a variable - makes sense. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$result = preg_replace('/slide \d+ of \d+/',"",$text); 
echo $result;
```

You need yo assign the replace to new variable and echo it. I guess you where trying to echo the `$text` after replace.

When i execute this :

```
$text = 'Test added for testing slide 1 of 6 should replaced with null';

$result = preg_replace('/slide \d+ of \d+/',"",$text);

echo $result;
```

I got the output as :

`Test added for testing should replaced with null`

Comment: It works fine for me, "view source" in browser and make it sure it is there.

Comment: I don't understand why it has to echo?

Comment: @Darko : your text after replace will be in `$result`, so to see this you need o echo `$result`